# Setting Grafana Variables with InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm studying Grafana with InfluxDB.
Multiple devices that I didn't set up appear.
I want to show only 1 device "69EAAA97", how can I do this?

[image]

[image]

Plus, there are lots of signals what I don't want.
How can I display the only signals which is in dbc file?

Thank you very much for your help.